# Matching multiple lines of Bold text with regex

Tags: regex, pdf, automation, adobe

I'm using AutoBookmark for Adobe Acrobat plugin which is utilizing regular expressions.
My expression is looking like this:
`(?<=WordToLookBehind\s\s)FirstWordInBold.*$`
So the script is giving me the exact number of bookmarks i need, but the problem is that sometimes Bold text is having a few newlines. Hence `.*$` is cutting the necessary string. What would be a possible solution?

Comment: Try `(?<=WordToLookBehind\s\s)FirstWordInBold.*\R*` or `(?<=WordToLookBehind\s\s)FirstWordInBold.*\s*`

Comment: Both expressions are reading bold text till the end of the row, but newlines are still missing

Comment: According to this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251418/can-i-match-bold-text-using-regular-expression regex lacks feature of matching text by such parameters as bold, italic etc...

Comment: That is right, regex matches text. You need something in the text to identify that it is bold.

Comment: Furthermore, seems like it's possible with HTML documents and [B\][a-zA-Z0-9._/ ]+\[/B\] expression. Ain't there specific tags for PDF files?